# Failed to Instert into Form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, insert

i am struggling with a PHP/Mysql Problem. I am not really into it, I just got this Script from an Guy who made me my website. Normally the Data which is entered in an form should be sent to an form. I created a Form with the name form1 and 16 Rows. The "ID" Row is Auto_increment and the Typ (int11), the rest 15 Rows are all (varchar20) with the type "latin1_swedish_ci"

My Script is following:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";

$vorname=$_POST["vorname"];
$Nachname=$_POST["Nachname"];
$Geburtsort=$_POST["Geburtsort"];
$bday=$_POST["bday"];
$strasse=$_POST["strasse"];
$Hausnummer=$_POST["Hausnummer"];
$Adresszusatz=$_POST["Adresszusatz"];
$Wohnort=$_POST["Wohnort"];
$PLZ=$_POST["PLZ"];
$Telefonnummer=$_POST["Telefonnummer"];
$Mail=$_POST["Mail"];
$select_familienstand=$_POST["select_familienstand"];
$select_arbeit=$_POST["select_arbeit"];
$Nettoeinkommen=$_POST["Nettoeinkommen"];



    $form_no=mt_rand(4,9);
    $_SESSION["FormNo"]=$form_no;
    $check_Form_No="SELECT * FROM form1 WHERE FormNo='$form_no'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$check_Form_No);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==0){
        $query="INSERT INTO form1 (`ID`, `FormNo`, `FirstName`, `Surname`, `POB`, `BirthDate`, `strabe`, `HouseNo`, `Address`, `POR`, `PostalCode`, `Phone`, `Email`, `MartialStatus`, `Employment`, `NetIncome`) VALUES('','$form_no','$vorname','$Nachname','$Geburtsort','$bday','$strasse','$Hausnummer','$Adresszusatz','$Wohnort','$PLZ','$Telefonnummer','$Mail','$select_familienstand','$select_arbeit','$Nettoeinkommen')";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($result){
            header("Location:../antrag2.php?Form_No=".$form_no);
        }else{
            echo "Failed To Insert";
            echo $query;
        }
    }else{
        echo "Already Data Found";
    }


?>
```

I would be really happy if someone could help me with this. The connection to the database works btw.I tested it with my connection.php file.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well the guy who made this didn't spend much time on security nor on code quality.

Comment: You don't want to use the `mysql_` functions, you want to use either `mysqli_` functions OR the PDO system.  Either of which you should be using prepared statements with.  I would re-start your insert process using either of those technologies, and get back with us when you have issues ...

Comment: Is someone interested to change these things for me for some Cash in Bitcoin? The problem is I am not able to change this. :/

Comment: No one interested? I would pay good for this. Just tell me where I can contact you.

Comment: This is not how SO works. If you want to contract someone use a freelancing site.